# Comparing a variable with itself in the previous year in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I still quite new to programming and have a bit of a problem which I haven't been able to find a solution to, although maybe part of that is because I don't know how to phrase my search query (English isn't my first language...). In any case, I have a dataset that is of the following format (simplified; there's data for more years and weeks, and many more goods):

| GoodID | Year | Week | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 3 | X1 |
| 1 | 2015 | 4 | Y1 |
| 1 | 2016 | 3 | Z1 |
| 1 | 2016 | 4 | U1 |
| 1 | 2017 | 3 | V1 |
| 1 | 2017 | 4 | W1 |
| 2 | 2015 | 3 | X2 |
| 2 | 2015 | 4 | Y2 |
| 2 | 2016 | 3 | Z2 |
| 2 | 2016 | 4 | U2 |

What I want to do is add a column that displays the price that a certain good had exactly one year ago. That is, it should display what the price was in the same week, but one year prior.

| GoodID | Year | Week | Price | Price last year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 3 | X1 | NA |
| 1 | 2015 | 4 | Y1 | NA |
| 1 | 2016 | 3 | Z1 | X1 |
| 1 | 2016 | 4 | U1 | Y1 |
| 1 | 2017 | 3 | V1 | Z1 |
| 1 | 2017 | 4 | W1 | U1 |
| 2 | 2015 | 3 | X2 | NA |
| 2 | 2015 | 4 | Y2 | NA |
| 2 | 2016 | 3 | Z2 | X2 |
| 2 | 2016 | 4 | U2 | Y2 |

I'm using tidyverse. Previously I was fine with just having the *average* across the years, which was easy enough:

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(GoodID, week)%>%
mutate(avgprice = mean(Price)) %>%
ungroup()
```

but when I want to compare prices with the ones a year prior I am completely lost. It sounds like something that should have an easy solution, something like

```
mutate(lastprice = Year-1$Price)
```

but obviously that doesn't work and I don't know how exactly I should word this. I have tried to filter the data

```
df <- df %>%
filter(year == 2017) %>%
mutate(lastprice = Price)

df <- df %>%
filter(year == 2016) %>%
mutate(lastprice = Price)
```

but this of course only resulted in the data entries from all other years being purged at the first try.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I can go about doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()` to access the value one row up. As long as we group by Good and Week and sort by year, that should give the previous year's price:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(GoodID, Week) %>%
  arrange(Year) %>%
  mutate(Price_Last_Year = lag(Price)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggested solution (for future posts, please include code so that your dataframe can be easily created so that people can test any responses):

```
df %>%
  arrange(week, year) %>%
  group_by(Good_ID, week) %>%
  mutate(price_last_year = lag(price))
```

The key aspect is `dplyr::lag()`, which takes care of referencing a value from a previous row. It is clever enough to introduce `NA`s at the boundaries (i.e. for the first entry in each group).

Comment: @MacAskill. Now it works! +/- It is the same answer as Gregor Thomas. At the same time!!! Upvote for both!!!

Comment: Yes, pretty much identical answer to Gegor but I think mine might have a redundant sort by `week`, which I guess is taken care of by the `group_by`, so I think he wins by the slightest margin of conciseness.